# Sonar webhook data 'stripped' in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I'm using Jenkins DSL multibranch build paired with Sonarqube community + Community branch plugin.
So far, I was using waitForQualityGate to get Sonar's quality gate results back in Jenkins and it was working as expected. I was checking qg.status to display Sonar status but, now I tried to include more detailed info (list of failed checks) on my job page.
Problem is that, on Jenkins side, JSON printout of waitForQualityGate is just:

```
{"status":"ERROR"}
```

When I check on Sonar side, I see that hook is executed with expected payload:

```
{
  "serverUrl": "http://localhost:9000",
  "taskId": "AXGhfNdNVsTZztVdmx-_",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "analysedAt": "2020-04-22T10:43:26+0000",
  "changedAt": "2020-04-22T10:43:26+0000",
  "project": {
    "key": "XXXXXX",
    "name": "XXXXXX",
    "url": "http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=XXXXXX"
  },
  "branch": {
    "name": "branch_name",
    "type": "SHORT",
    "isMain": false,
    "url": "http://localhost:9000/project/issues?branch=branch_name&id=XXXXXX&resolved=false"
  },
  "qualityGate": {
    "name": "MY_quality_gate",
    "status": "ERROR",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "metric": "new_reliability_rating",
        "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
        "value": "1",
        "status": "OK",
        "errorThreshold": "1"
      },
      {
        "metric": "new_security_rating",
        "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
        "value": "1",
        "status": "OK",
        "errorThreshold": "1"
      },
      {
        "metric": "new_maintainability_rating",
        "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
        "value": "3",
        "status": "ERROR",
        "errorThreshold": "1"
      },
      {
        "metric": "new_coverage",
        "operator": "LESS_THAN",
        "value": "100.0",
        "status": "OK",
        "errorThreshold": "90"
      }
    ]
  },
  "properties": {}
}
```

Please note that payload have status=SUCCESS and `qualityGate.status=ERROR` while, on Jenkins side, it defines `status=ERROR` and no qualityGate node at all?

Within job console log I can find:
[Pipeline] waitForQualityGate

```
Checking status of SonarQube task 'AXGh4vchVsTZztVdmx_J' on server 'SonarQube'
SonarQube task 'AXGh4vchVsTZztVdmx_J' status is 'SUCCESS'
SonarQube task 'AXGh4vchVsTZztVdmx_J' completed. Quality gate is 'ERROR'
```

I can not find any settings on Jenkins side that could be related to this issue (standard settings are set and normally working).

Version used:
Jenkins: 2.150.1
SonarQube Scanner plugin: 2.8.1
Sonarqube: 7.7.0.23042

Thx in advance for any tips or suggestions...